# How do i install apps like VLC or Chrome without using terminal?

Tags: software-installation, 18.04

My Ubuntu 18.04 Software Centre isn't showing VLC or other applications I want. If I search for "vlc", there are only a few apps...

What should I do?

Comment: VLC is available in Software Center via snap. I think your snap is creating problem.

Comment: Before doing anything ,it's beter to execute 'sudo apt update ; sudo apt upgrade' in terminal and then work with ubuntu software center

Answer (score 0):

In my experience,
synaptic is the best linux graphical package manager

To install it ,
simply type the following commands in terminal

```
sudo apt update ; sudo apt install synaptic
```

After installing it,
Use the search button to find apps

Then Select the app and click apply to install it

[image: synaptic ui]